# pymongo: Best way to query by reference?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a bunch of `Paper` documents in a `Papers` collection. Each `Paper` has one DBRef to a `Person` document. So the person property in a `Paper` document is a DBRef to the correct `Person`

Person

```
{'name' : 'Person A', 'slug' : 'PA'},
{'name' : 'Person B', 'slug' : 'PB'}
```

Paper

```
{'name' : 'Paper 1', 'person': DBRef},
{'name' : 'Paper 2', 'person': DBRef},
{'name' : 'Paper 3', 'person': DBRef}
```

I would like to create a query that returns all papers that reference Person A (slug=='PA'). I tried filtering in a query, and failed at a map reduce statement. What is the best way to handle this in pymongo?

**This query returns no results**

```
for paper in db['papers'].find({'person.slug' : 'PA'}): 
    print paper
```

**Map Reduce also returns zero results**

```
mapper = Code("""
                function () {
                if (this.person.slug == slug) {
                        emit (this, 1);
                        }
                }
    """)

    reducer = Code("""
        function (key, values) {
            return key;
        }
    """)
    result = db['papers'].map_reduce(mapper, reducer, "myresults",  scope={'slug' : 'PA'})
    for doc in result.find():
        print doc
```

Comment: Two subsequent queries, one to get the `_id` of Person A, and one to get the papers which reference that ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though I can do it like this, and I can't use other properties

```
for paper in db['papers'].find({'person.$id' : person['_id']}):
```